# Superimpose a networkx graph and a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, networkx

I have two figures:

1) networkx graph

2) a normal x-y plot.

1) The variable 'graph' is the Graph created using networkx. 'var' is x-y coordinates of the nodes of graph.

2) Also, I have two plot few points using scatter plot that will super impose on some of the existing points. I tried the following code. coors are the coordinates of x-y plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(nx.draw(graph,[(x,y) for x,y in var],node_size=50))
ax.scatter(coors[:,0],coors[:,1])
plt.show()
```

When I plot each of them separately it works but when I try to plot it together only the networkx comes up. I know they are different because scatter plot is in blue color and networkx graph is in a kinda orange color. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Can you give a complete example?  I'd like to be able to copy and paste and have it run immediately.  Right now I have to make guesses about what `var` looks like and what `coors` looks like and how they were defined originally.

Comment: "var" is a 2D numpy array - The two columns denotes x and y coordinates of points.
"graph" is defined as follows:
 
graph = nx.Graph()
for node in range(len(var)):
    graph.add_node(node)
    graph.add_edges_from(a)   
ls

Comment: Please discard the previous comment.. Sorry about that...
"var" is a 2D numpy array - The two columns denotes x and y coordinates of points.
"graph" is defined as follows:
 ---
graph = nx.Graph()
for node in range(len(var)):
    graph.add_node(node)
    graph.add_edges_from(a)   
---
"a" is again a two dimensional numpy array which denotes connectivity between two nodes. the connectivity was obtained from adjacency matrix. total number of nodes is the no of 2D points denoted in the "var" numpy array.

"coors" denoted the 2D numpy array. It is again x and y coordinates.

Comment: I can give you a small example of square with 4 vertices(nodes) connected by its edges. That's the graph. Two points defined by "coors" gets embedded on it. Two things to be displayed on the same figure.
***var = [[0 0][0 1][1 0][1 1]] -- coordinates x,y***
There are a total of 4 points and I denote them as 0,1,2,3. The connectivity is defined as, follows "a" = [[0 1][0 3][1 0][1 2][2 1][2 3][3 0][3 2]]*** Finally coors is again a 2D array of (x,y) points. "coors"=[[0 1][1 0]]***

Comment: I hope the comment above makes sense. I am not sure how to format it properly

Comment: it would help to edit your question and give code that generates that example